# "No integers $x$ and $y$ exist for $28x+7y=8$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

What is the logical structure of this statement?

> No integers $x$ and $y$ exist for $28x+7y=8.$

I'm not sure, but I think the answer is
$$¬∃x\;∃y\;(x ∈ \mathbb Z ∧ y ∈ \mathbb Z ∧ 28x + 7y = 8).$$

Comment: The second existence quantifier should also be negated explicitly. Why didn't you just write $\forall \,x,y\in \mathbb{Z} \, : \,28x+7y\neq 8$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MariusS.L. what do you mean that the second existential quantified needs a negation?

Comment: @Pdubya_24 I meant $\lnot (\exists x\in \mathbb{Z})\wedge \lnot (\exists y\in \mathbb{Z}) \ldots$

Comment: @Pdubya_24 However, I would really either apply the logic convention from a textbook, or, as it is about discrete mathematics and not logic, write it without negated existence. For all pairs $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\, : \,28x+7y\neq 8.$ This is much clearer.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Unless I'm misunderstanding it, $\lnot (\exists x\in \mathbb{Z})\wedge \lnot (\exists y\in \mathbb{Z})$ is still incorrect, and inconsistent with the last line of my answer (the one that you just quoted). For example, notice that the given natural-language sentence *is* consistent with $\left(0,\frac87\right)$ being a solution.

Comment: @ryang Yes, it would probably be better to talk about $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ from the beginning since I am sure this is what has been meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer (in blue) looks good. It is equivalent to Marius's suggested formalisation (in red; however, I don't think his comment's first sentence is correct):

\begin{align}
&\color{blue}{¬\,∃x\;\;∃y\;\;(x ∈ \mathbb Z \quad∧\quad y ∈ \mathbb Z \quad∧\quad 28x + 7y = 8)}
\\\equiv
{}&∀x\;\;∀y\;\;¬\,(x ∈ \mathbb Z \quad∧\quad y ∈ \mathbb Z \quad∧\quad 28x + 7y = 8)
\\\equiv
{}&∀y\;\;(∀x\;\;(x \not∈ \mathbb Z \quad∨\quad (y \not∈ \mathbb Z \quad∨\quad 28x + 7y \not= 8)))
\\\equiv
{}&\color{red}{∀y\;\;(∀x\;\;(x ∈ \mathbb Z \implies (y ∈ \mathbb Z \implies 28x + 7y \not= 8)))}
\\\equiv
{}&∀y\;\;(∀x{∈} \mathbb Z \;\;(y ∈ \mathbb Z \implies 28x + 7y \not= 8))
\\\equiv
{}&∀x{∈} \mathbb Z\;\; (∀y\;\;(y ∈ \mathbb Z \implies 28x + 7y \not= 8))
\\\equiv
{}&\color\red{∀x{∈} \mathbb Z\;\; ∀y{∈} \mathbb Z \quad 28x + 7y \not= 8}\tag1
\\\equiv
{}&\color{blue}{¬\,∃x{∈} \mathbb Z\;\; ∃y{∈} \mathbb Z \quad 28x + 7y = 8}\tag2
\\\equiv
{}&\color{blue}{¬\,∃(x,y){∈} \mathbb Z^2 \quad 28x + 7y = 8}\tag3
\\\equiv
{}&\color{red}{∀(x,y){∈}\mathbb Z^2 \quad 28x + 7y \not= 8}.\tag4
\end{align}

More plainly: $$28x + 7y = 8 \text{ has no integral solution set.}$$